# USB tethering & charging

Tags: samsung, charging, usb-tethering

I am experiencing weird problem related to charging my Android phone. Most of the time I have phone connected to laptop and use it as 4G/5G modem. I noticed that compared with older phones it draws more power from wall. Unfortunately USB ports on laptop provide only small power. I haven't measured it but guess it is 500 mA. It is sufficient to power the phone and also charge it. But the charging is very slow in the range 1-3 % / hour. Therefore I bought USB hub with charging functionality and inserted it between android phone and laptop. This USB hub have external 2A power input. Now the charging speed is acceptable (10-15% / hour). It is not super fast but its OK. But there are two problems:

1. If i physically disconnect USB hub from laptop and connect phone to one of USB ports, it starts charging. After about second or two charging stops. Disconnecting and connecting cable again doesn't help. But I noticed that if I reconnect USB cable that is powering hub, charging successfully starts. What is the reason for this behavior ? This is not cricitical problem for me. I can connect the phone directly to USB wall charger and there is no problem with this. But I would like to understand this.
2. Second more sinister problem is that sometimes while tethering internet connection in above configuration the phone charging stops. For a few months I thought that this is random problem which happened several times per month. After few months experience I think it is somehow related to USB headset I am using for internet calls. This problem with charging happened twice when I had long internet call. After few hours I noticed that phone battery charge level dropped 15-20 %. It is not a big deal when the battery is new. It could be problem when the battery will become older. The phone will then shutdown which is not acceptable because I use it to connect to my employer while I am working from home. It is probable that phone battery aging is accelerated in this configuration because the battery is most of the time fully charged. This problem with occasionaly not charging happens whether there is USB hub between phone and laptop or not (so the phone is connected to laptop directly). To me it seems as serious bug. Battery powered devices like this phone are on market more than 10 years so I its weird that manufacturers were not able to tune out such basic functionality. All the software functions, nice graphics and frequent updates are of no use if you cannot power the device. What is the reason for this behavior and is there some workaround for it ?

My hardware configuration:
Samsung Galaxy A33 5G SM-A336BZKGEEE
Laptop HP ENVY 15-as103nc
AXAGON HUE-S2BP 4-Port USB 3.0 CHARGING Hub (with 2A power source)
USB repeater AXAGON ADR-205, 5 m
Headset Behringer BH470U

My software configuration:
One UI 6.0
Android 14
Core version 5.10.177-android12-9-27775596-abA336BXXS8DXA1
Windows 10 Pro 22H2

The phone has charging limited to 85% by using android function. I had enabled developer options and set automatic tethering (it is not fully automatic - I have to unlock screen to enable usb tethering). Don't know if this is related to above problems or not.

Comment: There are multiple "standards" to charge a phone with more than 500ms @ 5V. Most of the older charging "standards" assume that you either have a data or a charger connection, some even require the data cables to be connected in a way making it impossible to use them for data transfer. May be your phone has problems detecting the used charging standard. The only standard to my knowledge that allows data and charging at the same time is USB Power Delivery (USB PD). If your USB hub and the phone would support it that would be the cleanest solution.